# Add title tag to image in wordpress gallery

Tags: gallery

I'm searching for a resolution which can add title attribute (`title=""`) to a WordPress gallery. Now, the code looks like this:

```
<img width="400" height="400" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/myimage-400x400.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="image alt desc">
```

I specified the title in the media editor, but the attribute is not showing in the image tag.

Comment: Are these images being added via the [gallery] shortcode or are you referring to inserting individual images? Note that the output will be different (and therefore, the answer) depending on how the images are being inserted into the post (and even whether they contain a caption or not).

Comment: @MariuszM I approved the edit from the queue. If you are the same user as the author, please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0):

The 'img' tag is built via the theme code for display on the page. So, you would have to modify the theme code to add to the img tag.

Note that modifying theme code directly is not generally advised, as a theme update will overwrite your changes. "Child" themes are best used for this modification.